# Docker Desktop for Windows GUI is not starting

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, docker-for-windows

I'm using Docker Desktop for Windows. It "suddenly" does not start. The `Docker Desktop.exe` process is running idle in the background. But there's no GUI, not even the tray icon.

It happened about same time on two machines running Windows 10. So I'd suspect some Windows Update. On one machine, reinstall of the Docker Desktop fixed the problem. But on the other machine, the reinstall did not help. On that machine I also happened to attempt an upgrade to Windows 11 about the same time, which failed (the system was rolled back to Windows 10). I suspect that might have contributed to the problem.

What I have tried:

- Removing and re-adding all Windows VM features: *Hyper-V*, *Virtual Machine Platform*, *Windows Hypervisor Platform*, *Windows Subsystem for Linux*.
- Removing and re-installing Docker Desktop
- I have downloaded missing `C:\Program Files\Linux Containers`
- `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers -All`

---

This is an output of `com.docker.diagnose.exe check`:

```
[005:14:38:31.140][I] ipc.NewClient: 0a5ab2b4-com.docker.diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2 com.docker.service.exe
[goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
[win/backend/pkg/service.NewClientForPath(...)
[   win/backend/pkg/service/service.go:26
[win/backend/pkg/service.NewClient(...)
[   win/backend/pkg/service/service.go:20
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.init()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/ipc_windows.go:23 +0x13b
Starting diagnostics

[PASS] DD0027: is there available disk space on the host?
[SKIP] DD0028: is there available VM disk space?
[FAIL] DD0031: does the Docker API work? error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine_linux/v1.24/containers/json?limit=0": open //./pipe/docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified.
[FAIL] DD0004: is the Docker engine running? Get "http://ipc/docker": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[005:14:38:31.377][I] ipc.NewClient: 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer LifecycleServer
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.NewClientForPath(...)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:64
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.NewClient(...)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:58
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:21 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc00051f7d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc00051f7d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc00051f7d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:31.377][I] (6047b638) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /docker
[005:14:38:31.378][E] (6047b638) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /docker (569.5µs): Get "http://ipc/docker": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:31.379][I] (6047b638-1) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /ping
[005:14:38:31.379][E] (6047b638-1) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:32.391][I] (6047b638-2) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /ping
[005:14:38:32.391][E] (6047b638-2) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:33.415][I] (6047b638-3) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /ping
[005:14:38:33.415][E] (6047b638-3) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:34.420][I] (6047b638-4) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /ping
[005:14:38:34.420][E] (6047b638-4) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:35.442][I] (6047b638-5) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /ping
[005:14:38:35.442][E] (6047b638-5) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:36.453][I] (6047b638-6) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /ping
[005:14:38:36.453][E] (6047b638-6) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (357.6µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:37.469][I] (6047b638-7) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /ping
[005:14:38:37.469][E] (6047b638-7) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (345.8µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:38.484][I] (6047b638-8) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C->S LifecycleServer GET /ping
[005:14:38:38.484][E] (6047b638-8) 0de2a6c7-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.(*lifecycleClient).GetDockerState(0xc00051f3f0)
[   linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:108 +0x5c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:22 +0x74
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x18273c0)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273

[FAIL] DD0011: are the LinuxKit services running? failed to ping VM diagnosticsd with error: Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerDiagnosticd: The system cannot find the file specified.
[005:14:38:38.484][I] ipc.NewClient: 62abc8a6-diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerDiagnosticd diagnosticsd
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.glob..func13()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/linuxkit.go:18 +0x4b
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x1827340)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x1827340)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x1827340)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x3, 0x1827340, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:38.484][I] (f6489133) 62abc8a6-diagnose C->S diagnosticsd GET /ping
[005:14:38:38.484][E] (f6489133) 62abc8a6-diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerDiagnosticd: The system cannot find the file specified.
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.glob..func13()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/linuxkit.go:19 +0x54
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x1827340)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x1827340)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0xfa9db7, 0x1827340)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x3, 0x1827340, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x18273c0, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827440, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0004337d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273

[PASS] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running?
[FAIL] DD0001: is the application running? Docker is not running
[SKIP] DD0018: does the host support virtualization?
[PASS] DD0002: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
[PASS] DD0017: can a VM be started?
[PASS] DD0024: is WSL installed?
[PASS] DD0021: is the WSL 2 Windows Feature enabled?
[PASS] DD0022: is the Virtual Machine Platform Windows Feature enabled?
[FAIL] DD0025: are WSL distros installed? WSL Distribution docker-desktop is missing
[PASS] DD0026: is the WSL LxssManager service running?
[FAIL] DD0029: is the WSL 2 Linux filesystem corrupt? exit status 0xffffffff
[PASS] DD0015: are the binary symlinks installed?
[PASS] DD0003: is the Docker CLI working?
[PASS] DD0013: is the $PATH ok?
[PASS] DD0005: is the user in the docker-users group?
[FAIL] DD0007: is the backend responding? failed to ping com.docker.backend with error: Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[005:14:38:41.759][I] ipc.NewClient: cc73a502-diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer BackendAPI
[common/pkg/backend.NewClientForPath(...)
[   common/pkg/backend/client.go:74
[common/pkg/backend.NewClient(...)
[   common/pkg/backend/client.go:68
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.glob..func8()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/ipc.go:25 +0x4c
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x1827740)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x1827740)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0x2, 0x1827740)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827740, 0xc0005ad7d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0005ad7d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273
[005:14:38:41.759][I] (ddb6bab5) cc73a502-diagnose C->S BackendAPI GET /ping
[005:14:38:41.759][E] (ddb6bab5) cc73a502-diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[common/pkg/backend.(*backendClient).Ping(0x11dcbce)
[   common/pkg/backend/client.go:80 +0x22
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.glob..func8()
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/ipc.go:26 +0x66
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x1827740)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x1827740)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0x2, 0x1827740)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:140 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x1827740, 0xc0005ad7d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:146 +0x36
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x100000000000000, 0xc0005ad7d8)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:149 +0x73
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x1119060, 0xc00051f918)
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:135 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x18275c0, 0xc0000682a0, {0xc00051fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[   common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1ce
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000403f0, 0xc0000403f0, 0x4}, {0x0, 0x0})
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:130 +0x105
[main.main()
[   common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:96 +0x273

2022/01/05 14:38:41 exit status 0xffffffff
```

Comments to some errors:

- ```
  //./pipe/docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified
  ```

  I get it even if I run `dockerd` manually. It says *"API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine"*. So that's why probably. `docker` cli can talk to the manually executed deamon.
- ```
  WSL Distribution docker-desktop is missing
  ```

  Indeed it is, the `wsl -l` says that there are no distributions. Though I do not think it's my immediate problem. Or is it?

Output of the `bcdedit /v`:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {9cb50143-12f1-11eb-b812-9101bbd8f403}
resumeobject            {9cb50142-12f1-11eb-b812-9101bbd8f403}
displayorder            {9cb50143-12f1-11eb-b812-9101bbd8f403}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {9cb50143-12f1-11eb-b812-9101bbd8f403}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {9cb50144-12f1-11eb-b812-9101bbd8f403}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {9cb50142-12f1-11eb-b812-9101bbd8f403}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

What else can I do to diagnose the problem? Or is there a way to reset the Docker? I know that there's "factory reset" function in the GUI, but obviously I cannot access it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Docker Desktop GUI logs to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Docker\log.txt`. Check the log to see, what is going wrong.

---

In my case, it was corrupted `%APPDATA%\Docker\locked-directories` file. I've removed the file and Docker Desktop GUI started working again.